# "Dudar" en forma negativa + el uso de los modos verbales después de "no dudar"

Tags: verbos, subjuntivo

Otro verbo que me hace llorar de desesperación es el verbo  «dudar» en forma negativa + el uso del subjuntivo después de este verbo.

Me han enseñado que se emplea el modo indicativo (en una oración en forma afirmativa) y el modo subjuntivo (en una oración en forma negativa). En el portal *Hispanoteca* encuentro la siguiente explicación:

a) No dudo que tienes razón.
(= veo que tienes razón)

b) No dudo que tengas razón.
(= tú dices que tienes razón, y te lo creo)

Francamente no veo ninguna diferencia en la explicación del uso de los modos.

Otro ejemplo:

> **El poema les pareció tan extraño a ellos que nadie dudó que en
>   realidad fuera escrito por este hombre.**

Me cuesta entender por qué se emplea el subjuntivo ya que diciendo «no dudo» niego la duda, ¿verdad? Además aquí tenemos «en realidad» que debería intensificar la certeza, ¿no?

He encontrado algunas líneas: *«el hablante se está refiriendo a algo que ha dicho otra persona o algo que ya ha sido manifestado en el contexto. El hablante rechaza o manifiesta su adhesión a lo manifestado en el contexto (rechazo contextual).»* ¿Será esta la explicación de uso del subjuntivo después de «no dudar»?

¡Gracias!

Comment: Buena pregunta. Yo tampoco veo diferencia entre las frases (a) y (b) lo único es que para la frase (b) casi que siempre esperaría un "pero" (sin que éste sea obligatorio) **No dudo que tengas razón, pero igual deberías disculparte**

Answer (score 1):

Realmente, sí hay una diferencia semántica (muy pequeña he de reconocer). En el primer caso, que realmente creo que no se usa, vemos evidencias de que el hecho que nos transmite el interlocutor es verdad. Sería igual a "Tienes razón".

En el caso b, no somos conscientes de que sea verdad el hecho pero nos lo creemos.

En la segunda frase de ejemplo, además creo que se acentúa con el uso de la expresión "en realidad" y el tiempo pasado. Pero es claramente el caso b. Por la manera de escribir creen que lo ha escrito esa persona. Pero en realidad no le han visto hacerlo.

Como he comentado al principio, creo que el primer caso realmente no se usa, y lo que pasa normalmente es que la gente al hablar usa indistintamente el indicativo y el subjuntivo, cuando en realidad lo correcto sería usar este último.

Answer (score 1):

Lo cierto es que ambas son correctas y, efectivamente, tienen significados ligeramente distintos.

El subjuntivo se utiliza (a grandes rasgos) para cosas que no son "hechos" (no tomar como regla rigurosa, por favor)

Básicamente la primera oración dice "no dudo que tienes razón". Al usar indicativo, indica que se trata de un hecho, y lo afirma. "que el otro tiene razón" es algo que no está en cuestión. Por tanto, esa frase probablemente continúa con "Lo que dudo es esto otro".

En cambio, en la segunda, utiliza el subjuntivo. Se debe a que "que el otro tenga razón" es algo que sí está en cuestión. La frase probablemente continúa con un "pero", o un "aunque.

No dudo que tienes razón, lo que digo es que...
vs
No dudo que tengas razón, aunque...

De todas formas, la segunda es siempre más correcta.

Answer (score 1):

Creo que el autor puso estas frases de ejemplos para (supuestamente) ayudar al estudiante a entender mejor el uso del subjuntivo.

Si ya te sientes bien con (b), por intuición, pues quédate con eso, y olvídate de (a), que en la práctica se usa muy poco, o nada.